# How does loc know which row to update when setting values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['Umbrella', 'Matress', 'Badminton',
                'Shuttle', 'Sofa', 'Football'],
    'MRP': [1200, 1500, 1600, 352, 5000, 500],
    'Discount': [0, 10, 0, 10, 20, 40]
})

# Print the dataframe
print(df)

df.loc[df.MRP >= 1500, "Discount"] = -1
print(df)
```

I want to understand how the `loc` works. The purpose of `loc` is to get the row by label search. But in the above code, it seems iterate over each row, and insert -1 in the new col where the boolean is True? Does it do label search?

Comment: Instead of guessing, print `df.MRP >= 1500`

Comment: I am not guessing anything - I want to understand how loc works when it is meant for searching by index value rather than position

Comment: It searches by index value when possible, and boolean when not. This is documented quite thoroughly. Did you read the docs for `loc`?

Answer (score 1):

The only "real" indexing on a DataFrame are the positional indexes (the 0 indexed values which correspond to the underlying structures).

`loc`, therefore, always has to "Convert a potentially-label-based key into a positional indexer." [_get_setitem_indexer](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L637).

---

Stepping out from under the hood the docs on [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) explicitly allow:

- A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an integer position along the index).
- A list or array of labels, e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'].
- A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'.
- A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True].
- An alignable boolean Series. The index of the key will be aligned before masking.
- An alignable Index. The Index of the returned selection will be the input.
- A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above).

---

The benefit of `loc` is that it is extraordinarily flexible, particularly in terms of being able to chain this with other operations:

See:

```
df.groupby('Discount')['MRP'].agg(sum)
```

```
Discount
0     2800
10    1852
20    5000
40     500
Name: MRP, dtype: int64
```

Filtering this with [`Series.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html#pandas-series-loc) can be written as:

```
df.groupby('Discount')['MRP'].agg(sum).loc[lambda s: s >= 1500]
```

```
Discount
0     2800
10    1852
20    5000
Name: MRP, dtype: int64
```

Another huge benefit of `loc` is its ability to index both dimensions:

```
df.loc[df['MRP'] >= 1500, ['Product', 'Discount']] = np.nan
```

```
    Product   MRP  Discount
0  Umbrella  1200       0.0
1       NaN  1500       NaN
2       NaN  1600       NaN
3   Shuttle   352      10.0
4       NaN  5000       NaN
5  Football   500      40.0
```

TLDR; The power of `loc` is its ability to *translate* various inputs into positional inputs, while the drawback is overhead of those conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the documentation for [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) states:

> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array.
>
> `.loc[]` is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array

Let's take a look at the expression `df.MRP >= 1500`. This is a boolean series with the same index as the dataframe:

```
>>> df.MRP >= 1500
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: MRP, dtype: bool
```

So clearly there is at least an opportunity to match labels. What happens when you remove the labels?

```
>>> df.loc[(df.MRP >= 1500).to_numpy(), "Discount"]

1    10
2     0
4    20
Name: Discount, dtype: int64
```

So `.loc` will use the ordering of the DataFrame when labels are not available. This makes sense. But does it use order or labels when the labels don't match?

Make a Series like `df.MRP >= 1500` but out of order to see what gets selected:

```
>>> ind1 = pd.Series([True, True, True, False, False, False], index=[1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 5])
>>> df.loc[ind1, "Discount"]
1    10
2     0
4    20
Name: Discount, dtype: int64
```

So clearly, when available label matching is happening. When not available, order is used instead:

```
>>> df.loc[ind1.to_numpy(), "Discount"]
0     0
1    10
2     0
Name: Discount, dtype: int64
```

Another interesting point is that the labels of the index expression must be a superset, not a subset of the DataFrame's index. For example, if you shorten `ind` by one element, this is what happens:

```
>>> ind2 = pd.Series([True, True, True, False, False], index=[1, 2, 4, 0, 3])
>>> df.loc[ind2, "Discount"]
...
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

and

```
>>> df.loc[ind2.to_numpy(), "Discount"]
...
IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 5 instead of 6
```

Adding an extra element when doing label matching is OK, however:

```
>>> ind3 = pd.Series([True, True, True, False, False, False, True], index=[1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 5, 6])
>>> df.loc[ind3, "Discount"]
1    10
2     0
4    20
Name: Discount, dtype: int64
```

Notice that element at index `6`, which is not in the DataFrame, is ignored in the output.

And of course without labels, longer arrays are not acceptable either:

```
>>> df.loc[ind3.to_numpy(), "Discount"]
...
IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 7 instead of 6
```